# OpenCV, How to Join / Fill gap in lines or box or circles (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, gaussian, canny-operator

I have a set of images which have boxes and circles contain numbers. Some boxes & circles are not connected across all sides, there some gap in lines.

[image]

I want to fill this gap (shown in image), anyone has any idea using OpenCV...?

My Code is here........

```
    self.res = cv2.imread("1.jpg")

    self.store_path = "../storage-data/" 

    #define kernal value
    kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)

    #grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    dilate = cv2.dilate(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
    dilate1 = cv2.dilate(dilate,kernel,iterations = 1)

    dilate1 = cv2.morphologyEx(dilate1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    #Canny
    canny = cv2.Canny(dilate1,160,160,3)

    dilate = cv2.dilate(canny,kernel,iterations = 1)

    #Gaussian Blurring
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(dilate,(5,5),0)
    erode = cv2.dilate(blur,kernel,iterations = 1)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(erode,(5,5),1)

    blur = cv2.morphologyEx(blur, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh,(5,5),1)
    ret1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    cv2.imwrite(self.store_path + 'opening.jpg', opening)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: There are a lot of different approaches to do so. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Grillteller, please check the updated question.

Answer (score 4):

One dilation should be enough, the key is to use a vertical kernel,
Try change the dimensions of the kernel
 e.g.
    kernel = np.ones((5,2),np.uint8)
Check the result after 1 dilation it should close the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using contours.Contours can be explained simply as a curve joining all the continuous points (along the boundary), having same color or intensity.First find all the countours and then draw the contours onto the original image.This will probably solve the issue

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny, 2,2)
length = len(contours)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, i, (0,255,0), 2, cv2.LINE_8)
```

Comment: I have already done this, need help in the filling gap in the lines of a box. (shown in the above image). Thanks